# Javascript - Class function which returns the filename of the script which constructed the class

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I've been working on a Discord.js bot although that won't matter that will give context. I am trying to make the command class include a `.getName()` function which will return the cleaned filename of the file in which the class is constructed. What I currently have is (scaled down)

```js
this.getName = () => require('path').basename(__filename).split(".")[0]
```

However, it saves the `__filename` variable from the class file. **So I was wondering if there was a way I can get the filename at the construction of the class?**
I am aware that I can pass in an argument although that is not the approach I want to take.

Comment: You can run `require('path').basename(__filename).split(".")[0]` in the constructor of your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snipped of code

> Blockquote

class dummyClass {

getFileName(){

return  require('path').basename(__filename).split(".")[0]
}

}

let myClass = new dummyClass()

let fileName = myClass.getFileName()
console.log('fileName: ', fileName);

> Blockquote

Comment: Thanks for trying but like a said my system is multi file based so that would return the filename of the module which defines the class, I am looking for a way to get the filename of which the class is constructed in.